# Manipulating Algebraic Expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> $a + b + c = 7$ and $\dfrac{1}{a+b} + \dfrac{1}{b+c} + \dfrac{1}{c+a} = \dfrac{7}{10}$. Find the value of $\dfrac{a}{b+c} + \dfrac{b}{c+a} + \dfrac{c}{a+b}$.

I algebraically manipulated the second equation to get:

$\dfrac{(b+c)(c+a) + (a+b)(c+a) + (a+b)(b+c)}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} = \dfrac{7}{10}$

$\dfrac{bc+ab+c^2+ac+a^2+bc+ba+ab+ac+b^2+bc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} = \dfrac{7}{10}$

$\dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} = \dfrac{7}{10}$

$\dfrac{7^2}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)} = \dfrac{7}{10}$

$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = 70$

I'm stuck after this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

$$\frac a{b+c}+\frac b{c+a}+\frac c{a+b}$$

$$=\frac a{b+c}+1-1+\frac b{c+a}+1-1+\frac c{a+b}+1-1$$

$$=-3+(a+b+c)\left(\frac 1{b+c}+\frac 1{c+a}+\frac 1{a+b}\right)$$

Using summation notation, $$\sum_{a,b,c} \frac a{b+c}=-3+\sum_{a,b,c} \left(\frac a{b+c}+1\right)=-3+(a+b+c)\sum_{a,b,c}\frac1{b+c}$$

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal, so the sum should be $-3+7\cdot \frac7{10}=\frac{-3\cdot10+49}{10}=\frac{19}{10}$

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I'm not familiar with your use of the sigma notation. I'm used to numbers written on top and on the bottom of the sigma. Can you explain what the notation means?

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal, $\sum \frac a{b+c}=\frac a{b+c}+\frac b{c+a}+\frac c{a+b}$

Comment: Thanks! So, in general, when somebody uses this notation, its just to add everything that comes after the term and looks similar?

Comment: @AnanayAgarwal,  please have a look into http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280372/cyclic-sums-how-do-you-use-them and http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum

Answer (score 4):

It is sometimes beneficial to start from the end
$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=$$
$$\frac{7-b-c}{b+c}+\frac{7-a-c}{a+c}+\frac{7-a-b}{a+b}=$$
$$7\left(\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{a+c}\right)-3=$$
$$\frac{49}{10}-3=\frac{19}{10}$$

Answer (score 3):

Here is another direct way of beginning by calculating directly from what you know:

$$(a+b+c)\left(\frac 1{a+b}+\frac 1{b+c}+\frac 1{c+a}\right)=\left(\frac c{a+b}+1\right)+\left(\frac a{b+c}+1\right)+\left(\frac b{c+a}+1\right)$$

and rearranging gives you what you need.