# Prove $\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{}\sqrt[3] {1+2ac} \le 3\sqrt [3] {3}$ for $ a+b+c+abc=4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

[The presented solution of the following problem on Art of Problem Solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1967299) using Jensen's inequality is wrong, since the function $f(x):=\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{2t}{x}} $ is convex rather than concave. How would one prove this inequality, correctly?

> Let $a, b ,c $ be positive real numbers such that $ a+b+c+abc=4$. Prove that :
> $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}^{}\sqrt[3] {1+2ac} \le 3\sqrt [3] {3}.$$

Comment: Can you clarrify what $\sum_{cyc}$ means?

Comment: @AdityaDeSaha: $\sum_{\text{cyc}}$ stands for cyclic summation, meaning the summing indices run through a cyclic permutation https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280372/cyclic-sums-how-do-you-use-them.

Comment: I can't open the link, says you must be registered user to view the content. (try opening in incognito mode to see exact message if you want)

Comment: @prosinac: Fixed it. How about now?

Comment: It's ok now. And yes, I agree solution is wrong, but I can't think of a right one now

Comment: @Macavity: Your inequality does not hold. Take $a=0, b=c=2.$

Comment: OK - that e.g. seems correct.  So my way wouldn’t have worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**(20230517)

WLOG, assume that $c = \min(a,b,c)$.

Since $x\mapsto \sqrt[3]{x}$ is concave on $(0, \infty)$, we have
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt[3]{1+2ac} + \sqrt[3]{1+2ba} + \sqrt[3]{1+2cb}
 &\le 2\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+2ac + 1+2cb}{2}} + \sqrt[3]{1+2ba}\\
 &= 2\sqrt[3]{1+ac + cb} + \sqrt[3]{1+2ba}. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

It suffices to prove that
$$2\sqrt[3]{1+ac + cb} + \sqrt[3]{1+2ba} \le 3\sqrt[3]{3}. \tag{2}$$

We split into two cases.

**Case 1**: $ba < 1$

Using $c = \min(a, b, c)$, we have $ac + cb \le 2ba\le 2$. Thus, (2) is true.

**Case 2**: $ba \ge 1$

From $a+b+c+abc = 4$, we have
$c = \frac{4-a-b}{ab+1}$. Also, we have $a+b \ge 2\sqrt{ab} > 2$.

Thus, we have $$ac + cb = \frac{(4-a-b)(a+b)}{ab + 1}
= \frac{4 - (a+b - 2)^2}{ab+1} \le \frac{4 - (2\sqrt{ab} - 2)^2}{ab+1}. \tag{3}$$

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$2\sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{4 - (2\sqrt{ab} - 2)^2}{ab+1}} + \sqrt[3]{1+2ba} \le 3\sqrt[3]{3}.$$

Let $x = \sqrt{ba}$. Then $1 \le x \le 2$. It suffices to prove that, for all $1\le x\le 2$,
$$2\sqrt[3]{1+ \frac{4 - (2x - 2)^2}{x^2+1}} + \sqrt[3]{1+2x^2} \le 3\sqrt[3]{3}$$
or
$$2\sqrt[3]{1 - \frac{2(3x-1)(x-1)}{3(x^2+1)}} + \sqrt[3]{\frac{1+2x^2}{3}} \le 3. \tag{4}$$

Let
$$A := 1 - \frac{2(3x-1)(x-1)}{3(x^2+1)}, \quad B := \frac{1+2x^2}{3}.$$
Then $0 < A \le 1$ and $B \ge 1$.

(4) is written as
$$\sqrt[3]{B} - 1 \le 2(1 - \sqrt[3]{A})$$
or
$$\frac{B - 1}{B^{2/3} + B^{1/3} + 1}
\le \frac{2(1 - A)}{A^{2/3} + A^{1/3} + 1}.$$

We have $B^{2/3} + B^{1/3} \ge 2\sqrt{B^{2/3} \cdot B^{1/3}} = 2\sqrt{B} = \frac{4B}{2\sqrt{B}} \ge \frac{4B}{B + 1}$.
Also, we have $A^{2/3} + A^{1/3} \le 2A^{1/3} 
\le 2\cdot \frac{A + 1 + 1}{3} = \frac{2A + 4}{3}$.

Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{B - 1}{\frac{4B}{B+1} + 1}
\le \frac{2(1 - A)}{\frac{2A + 4}{3} + 1}$$
or
$$\frac{2(x-1)(x+1)(x^2+2)}{15x^2 + 12} \le \frac{12(3x-1)(x-1)}{15x^2 + 16x + 23}$$
or
$$\frac{2(x+1)(x^2+2)}{15x^2 + 12} \le \frac{12(3x-1)}{15x^2 + 16x + 23}$$
or (after clearing the denominators)
$$-15\,{x}^{4}-46\,{x}^{3}+155\,{x}^{2}-20\,x+118 \ge 0$$
which is true. Indeed, we have
$$\mathrm{LHS} \ge -15x^2 \cdot 2^2 - 46x^2 \cdot 2 + 155x^2 - 20 \cdot 2 + 118 = 3x^2 + 78 > 0.$$

We are done.

Comment: Looks nice, but could you please explicitly prove the last inequality?

Comment: @Hans  I updated it.

Comment: +1. Impressive proof, overall! How do you come up with the relaxed inequality $(1)$ especially when the application of $\sqrt[3]{1+u} \le 1 + \frac{u}{3}$ to both cubic roots would have failed?

Comment: @Hans  First, try simple bounds, if not enough, try better bounds.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR

A standard computer-assisted (but rigorous) proof is to use [Lagrange multipliers method](http://ramanujan.math.trinity.edu/wtrench/texts/TRENCH_LAGRANGE_METHOD.PDF) together with interval arithmetic libraries such as [`IntervalRoots.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalRootFinding.jl).

---

We are optimizing within a compact set in $\mathbb R^3$ as shown below

[image]

So there exist maximum points, either in the interior, or on the boundaries.

We can use Lagrange method for the interior.
Let
$$
f(a, b, c)=\sqrt[3]{2 a b+1}+\sqrt[3]{2 a c+1}+\sqrt[3]{2 b c+1}-3 \sqrt[3]{3}
$$
and
$$
g(a,b,c,l) = f(a,b,c)+l (a b c+a+b+c-4).
$$
Then we just to find the critical points of $g$, i.e., solve $\nabla g = 0$, i.e., 
\begin{align}
\frac{2 b}{3 (2 a b+1)^{2/3}}+\frac{2 c}{3 (2 a c+1)^{2/3}}+l (b c+1)&=0, \\
\frac{2 a}{3 (2 a b+1)^{2/3}}+l (a c+1)+\frac{2 c}{3 (2 b c+1)^{2/3}}&=0, \\
l (a b+1)+\frac{2 a}{3 (2 a c+1)^{2/3}}+\frac{2 b}{3 (2 b c+1)^{2/3}}&=0, \\
a b c+a+b+c-4&=0.
\end{align}
Look at this for a while and you will see that one solution is
$$
a=b=c=1, l = -\frac{2}{3\ 3^{2/3}}
$$
and this should give us the maximum of $f(1,1,1)=0$.
To rule out other solutions, we can use **rigorous numerics** libararies like [`IntervalRoots.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaIntervals/IntervalRootFinding.jl).

It's not difficult to see that the solution $(a,b,c,l)$ can only be within $[0,4]^3 \times [-55,0]$. The following Julia code finds all such solutions **rigorously**.

```
using IntervalArithmetic, IntervalRootFinding, ForwardDiff

f((a, b, c)) = -3*3^(1/3) + (1 + 2*a*b)^(1/3) + (1 + 2*a*c)^(1/3) + (1 + 2*b*c)^(1/3)
g((a, b, c, l))=f((a, b, c))+l*(a + b + c + a*b*c - 4)
∇g = ∇(g)
box = IntervalBox(0..4,3)×(-55..0)
rts = roots(∇g, box, Krawczyk, 1e-5)
println(rts)
```

And the result is

```
Root{IntervalBox{4,Float64}}[Root([0.999999, 1.00001] × [0.999999, 1.00001] × [0.999999, 1.00001] × [-0.3205, -0.320499], :unique)]
```

To see why only chekcing $l \in [-55,0]$ suffices, note that
$$
l = -\frac{2 \left(c (2 a b+1)^{2/3}+b (2 a c+1)^{2/3}\right)}{3 (2 a b+1)^{2/3} (2 a c+1)^{2/3} (b c+1)}
$$
Using $a, b, c \ge 0$ at the bottom and $a, b, c \le 4$ at the top shows that $l > -55$.

This in fact **proves** (not just verifies) our conjecture that there is only one solution of $\nabla g=0$ (if there is no bug in the library).

However, to be sure that maximum points do not appear on the boundary, we still need to check, for instance $a=0$.
This reduces to find maximum of
$$
\sqrt[3]{2 (4-c) c+1}-3 \sqrt[3]{3}+2,
$$
which is
$$
2-3 \sqrt[3]{3}+3^{2/3} < 0
$$
when $c = 2$.

Comment: By "minimum", you actually mean maximum, right? 1) The solution you found is a stationary point. But why is it the maximum? 2) Could you please show "the solution $(a,b,c,l)$ can only be within $[0,4]^3 \times [-55,0]$"?

Comment: @Hans, Thanks. It should be maximum. I choose the range because $a,b,c$ can only be in $[0,4]$ and you can see easily from the equations that $l$ can not be less than $-55$.

Comment: Sure, ,,∈[0,4], but why $l\ge-55$? More essentially, could you please answer question 1) of my last comment?

Comment: I like the way you intentionally used bold font for the words that sound suspicious. I am suspicious, but it seems like a great library! Also the approach to solution is nice and automated, although, I'm sure that there is a "nice" solution to this problem. As for questions, it shows it's a stationary point, and to see it's max you only need to verify that at edges, the values are less than at that point. This is easy for $a, b, c$ edges, and for $l$ I can't see it now but hope it is not a big problem.

Comment: @prosinac: If you claim checking the edges is not problem, please show it is not. Otherwise, it does **not** constitute a proof!

Comment: @Hans I've written down why $-55$ is enough and also the verification of the boundaries.

Comment: +1. This looks legitimate though I was a bit skeptical at the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

*My second proof*.

It suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}\sqrt[3]{\frac{1 + 2ac}{3}} \le 3.$$

**Fact 1**. It holds that $\sqrt[3]{x} \le -\frac{1}{18}x^2 + \frac49x + \frac{11}{18}$
for all $x\in [0, 3]$.
(*Proof*: We have
$\mathrm{RHS}^3 - \mathrm{LHS}^3 = \frac{(x - 1)^2}{5832}(-x^4 + 22x^3 - 114x^2 - 266x + 1331)\ge 0$ for all $x\in [0, 3]$.)

Note that $\frac{1+2ac}{3} \le 3, \frac{1+2ba}{3}\le 3, \frac{1+2cb}{3}\le 3$ (easy by AM-GM). By Fact 1, it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left[-\frac{1}{18}\left(\frac{1+2ac}{3}\right)^2 + \frac49\left(\frac{1+2ac}{3}\right) + \frac{11}{18}\right] \le 3$$
or
$$a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 - 11(ab + bc + ca) + 30 \ge 0$$
or (after homogenization)
$$a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2 - 11(ab + bc + ca)\cdot \left(\frac{a + b + c}{3}\right)^2 + 30\left(\frac{a + b + c}{3}\right)^4 \ge 0. \tag{1}$$

We use the pqr method.

Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r = abc$.
(1) is written as
$$10p^4 - 33p^2q - 54pr + 27q^2 \ge 0. \tag{2}$$

Using $q^2 \ge 3pr$, it suffices to prove that
$$10p^4 - 33p^2q - 54p\cdot \frac{q^2}{3p} + 27q^2 \ge 0$$
or
$$(p^2 - 3q)(10p^2 - 3q) \ge 0$$
which is true using $p^2 \ge 3q$.

We are done.