# Closed form expressions for $T_n$ and $S_n$ of a Fibonacci-like sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, terminology, fibonacci-numbers

I am a student curious about recurrence relations who has just bumped into the Intermediate 1st year (grade 11).

I derived the closed form expressions for the $n^{th}$ term and the sum of $n$ terms of a Fibonacci-like sequence of the form $(a,b,a+b,a+2b,2a+3b,...)$ by substituting $a_n=x^n$ into the characteristic recurrence relation: $a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+a_n$.

I want to know what this method ($a_n=x^n$) is called, and if the below mentioned expressions are already documented somewhere. I would also like to know if there are simpler versions of these expressions.

$$T_n=\sum_{r \in \{{\phi,\psi\}}}{r^n \left(\frac{T_1}{3r+1}+\frac{T_2}{r+2}\right)}$$
$$S_n=\left(\sum_{r\in\{\phi,\psi\}}{r^n\left(\frac{T_1+T_2}{3r+1}+\frac{T_1+2T_2}{r+2}\right)}\right)-T_2$$
where,
$T_n = n^{th}$ term of the Fibonacci-like sequence.
$S_n =$ sum of $n$ terms of the Fibonacci-like sequence.
$\phi,\psi$ are the roots of the equation: $x^2-x-1=0$

Also, I saw other answers mentioning the closed form expressions for $T_n$ using Binet's formula and other methods, but I could not find a closed form expression for $S_n$ in any of those.

These work over every Fibonacci-like sequence. I would love suggestions on the improvement of these expressions.

Thank You.

**EDIT:** There seems to be some confusion around the summation in the comments. Here is an example that completely explains it.

Let's consider the Fibonacci sequence:$$1,1,2,3,5,8,...$$

Let's verify the formulas for the 6th term and the sum of the first 6 terms of the Fibonacci sequence using the expressions provided above.

First, let's calculate the 6th term ($T_6$) of the Fibonacci sequence:

$$T_6 = \sum_{r \in \{\phi,\psi\}}{r^6\left(\frac{T_1}{3r+1}+\frac{T_2}{r+2}\right)}$$

We know the first two terms of the Fibonacci sequence are $T_1 = 1$ and $T_2 = 1$, and we'll use the roots of the characteristic equation, $\phi$ and $\psi$, which are approximately $\phi \approx 1.61803$ and $\psi \approx -0.61803$.

Substituting these values into the formula:

$$T_6 = \left(\phi^6\left(\frac{1}{3\phi+1}+\frac{1}{\phi+2}\right)\right) + \left(\psi^6\left(\frac{1}{3\psi+1}+\frac{1}{\psi+2}\right)\right)$$

After evaluating this expression, we get $T_6 \approx 8$.

Next, let's calculate the sum of the first 6 terms of the Fibonacci sequence ($S_6$):

$$S_6 = \left(\sum_{r \in \{\phi,\psi\}}{r^6\left(\frac{T_1+T_2}{3r+1}+\frac{T_1+2T_2}{r+2}\right)}\right)-T_2$$

Substituting the known values:

$$S_6 = \left(\phi^6\left(\frac{1+1}{3\phi+1}+\frac{1+2}{\phi+2}\right)\right) + \left(\psi^6\left(\frac{1+1}{3\psi+1}+\frac{1+2}{\psi+2}\right)\right) - 1$$

After evaluating this expression, we get $S_6 \approx 20$.

The values obtained from the formulas match the actual values of the 6th term and the sum of the first 6 terms of the Fibonacci sequence, confirming the correctness of the expressions provided above.

Comment: What does "$\sum_{\phi, \psi}$" mean?

Comment: A cyclic summation.

Comment: You'll have to back up further. I see no variable that can change in the summation.

Comment: Those variables are actually $\phi$ and $\psi$.

Comment: You've already defined those to be constants.  To me, this notation is just as unclear as $$\sum_{1,2} (2+3+4)$$ except that instead of $1$ and $2$ you have $\frac{1 \pm \sqrt5}{2}$.

Comment: It is valid mathematical notation, $\phi=\frac{1+√5}{2}$, so first you go summing the term with $\phi$ and then with $\psi$ (just replacing $\phi$ with $\psi$), which is equal to $\frac{1-√5}{2}$. Is this a clear explanation or will I have to explain more?

Comment: If you put $x=1, y=2, z=3$ then $\sum_{x,y,z}{x}=x+y+z=1+2+3=6$.

Comment: It is now a clear explanation, but it is still bad notation. I disagree that $\sum_{x,y,z} x = x+y+z$, in all cases but *especially* if $x$, $y$, and $z$ have already been defined.

Comment: Please have a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/280372/cyclic-sums-how-do-you-use-them for more info on cyclic summation notation.

Comment: You say that those are constants, not variables. But to say for the notation, they may be first used as variables then the calculation follows to take the roots of the equation. Phi and Psi can be any variables in math, here they are given a constant value from the quadratic after the cyclic summation in declared. Hence it is valid.

Comment: There is *one* instance of someone using this notation in the linked post, and in my opinion that instance is also bad! There are two good alternatives that are easy to read for someone who does not habitually think about inequality problems. One is $$\sum_{r \in \{\phi,\psi\}}{r^n(\frac{T_1}{3r+1}+\frac{T_2}{r+2})}.$$ Another is to define the roots as $r_1$ and $r_2$, then sum an expression in $r_i$ for $i$ going from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: Based on the answer you've gotten, you seem to be having a second struggle with unconventional terminology, where you're calling *any* sequence satisfying $a_n = a_{n-1} - a_{n-2}$ a "Fibonacci sequence" even if it does not satisfy the initial conditions of the Fibonacci sequence. (This is fine, if a bit weird, but you should say that you're doing this, because otherwise people will assume that you mean the Fibonacci sequence with $F_0=0$ and $F_1=1$.)

Comment: That summation notation is awful. Please use the one suggested by @MishaLavrov.

Comment: All of the comments have been addressed and the question is further rectified and confusions cleared out.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Ma'am, on what platform do you teach math to high school students? I am interested.

Comment: Why not just use Binet’s formula and sum the geometric series? Idk where you got your $S_n$,$T_n$, but they’re over complicated (and not clearly correct).

Comment: @Eric I don't know what you mean by summing the geometric series, but the Binet's formula only works for one Fibonacci sequence and not with other Fibonacci-like sequences where the first and second terms may be different.

Comment: @YatharthShrivastava It is Sir, not Ma'am (the name Misha is a male one in Russian, though I have the impression that it varies over the globe), and the platform is Canada/USA Mathcamp, a summer program in the US.

Comment: Ahh, misunderstood - then I’m not sure how you can get much simpler than $\sum_{i,r} a_{i,j} T_i r_j^n$ where you’ve defined the coefficients $a_{i,j}$ in terms of $r$

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh! I am sorry sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's an official name for the $a_n = x^n$ method - maybe the "ansatz method", since one name for a substitution like $a_n = x^n$ is an "ansatz".

The simplest closed form I can think of for a sequence that satisfies $T_n = T_{n-1} + T_{n-2}$ in terms of $\phi$ and $\psi$ is $$T_n = \frac{(T_1 - T_0\psi)\cdot \phi^n - (T_1 - T_0\phi)\cdot \psi^n}{\phi - \psi}.$$ This can be obtained by writing $T_n = A \phi^n + B \psi^n$, then setting $n=0$ and $n=1$ to solve for $A$ and $B$.  (When $T_0 = 0$ and $T_1 = 1$, this reduces to Binet's formula.)

In some cases, our base case for the recurrence is $T_1$ and $T_2$, rather than $T_0$ and $T_1$. In that case, $T_0$ "should have been" $T_2 - T_1$ to satisfy the Fibonacci recurrence, and we can replace $T_0$ by $T_2 - T_1$ in the formula above. It's a tiny bit messier, that way.

Compared to the formula in the question, we are trading off a constant factor like $\frac{T_1}{3\phi + 1} + \frac{T_2}{\phi+2}$ for $\frac{T_1 - T_0\psi}{\phi-\psi}$ or $\frac{T_1 \psi^2 - T_2\psi}{\phi - \psi}$. These are equal when $\phi$ and $\psi$ are the two roots of $x^2-x-1=0$.

---

For $S_n$, we can observe that $S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} = S_n - T_2$. Proof: $$S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} = \sum_{k=2}^n T_{k-1} + \sum_{k=3}^n T_{k-2} = T_1 + \sum_{k=3}^n (T_{k-1} + T_{k-2}) = T_1 + \sum_{k=3}^n T_k,$$ which includes every term of $S_n$ except for $T_2$. It follows that $(S_{n-1} + T_2) + (S_{n-2} + T_2) = (S_n + T_2)$, so the sequence $\hat S_n := S_n + T_2$ also satisfies the Fibonacci recurrence. We can therefore use the same formula as above for it, with the initial condition $\hat S_0 = T_2$ and $\hat S_1 = T_3$. After subtracting $T_2$ from the result, we conclude $$S_n = \hat S_n - T_2 = \frac{(T_3 - T_2\psi)\cdot \phi^n - (T_3 - T_2\phi)\cdot \psi^n}{\phi - \psi} - T_2.$$ We can also spot that if $\hat S_0 = T_2$ and $\hat S_1 = T_3$, then in general we'll have $\hat S_n = T_{n+2}$, and therefore $S_n = T_{n+2} - T_2$.

Comment: That's a really neat expression! Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had tried to find the sum until nth term for fibonacci once, and I would suggest a much simpler way. Here was my approach:

$F_{k} = F_{k+1} - F_{k-1}$

$F_{k-1} = F_{k} - F_{k-2}$

$F_{k-2} = F_{k-1} - F_{k-3}$

$F_{k-3} = F_{k-2} - F_{k-4}$

$F_{k-4} = F_{k-3} - F_{k-5}$

...

$F_{3} = F_{4} - F_{2}$

$F_{2} = F_{3} - F_{1}$

$F_{1} = F_{2} - F_{0}$

Therefore, the sum telescopes: cancelling every term except $F_{k+1} + F_{k} - F_{1} - F_{0} $

Which simplifies to $F_{k+2}-F_{2} = F_{k+2} - 1$

Now, for a closed form expression you can simply plug this into the Binets formula and get the closed form:

$$S_{k}= \frac{\left(\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{k+2} - \left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^{k+2}}{\sqrt5} -1 $$

Comment: The $S_n$ must be in the terms of first and second term. You just put the values of $\phi$ and $\psi$. What is $k$ in your formula? You did not define it.

Comment: Sorry I meant n instead of k, a typo

Comment: I am really confused about how to use it for other fibonacci sequences like $0,1,1,2,...$, or $4,5,9,14,...$, etc. that have other first and second terms.

Answer (score 0):

Let $<T_n>$ be a Fibonacci-like sequence with first and second terms with $a$ and $b$.

Then a closed formula expression for $T_n$ is given by the formula in Misha Lavrov's response, plugging in $T_0=a$ and $T_1=b$.

By the telescoping method desribed in Initial_Velocity's response, we obtain the closed formula expression $$S_n=T_{n+1}+T_n-T_1-T_0=T_{n+1}-T_n-b-a.$$